# sparql check for existing of a property and give zero to the answer

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is my minimum data:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>

:item :hasContext [:weight 0.1 ; :doNotRecommend true] , [:weight 0.2 ] .

:anotherItem :hasContext [:weight 0.4] , [ :weight 0.5 ] .
```

as you see, each `item` has **one or more** `hasContext` , the object of that `hasContext` is an instance that **could** have a `doNotRecommed` predicate.

What I want is that if one of these instances (that are object of a hasContext) contains the donNotRecommed, i want the whole sum to be zero. ** and by sum I mean the sum of the weight**, so in other words, if that property exist, ignore all the weights (either they were there or not), just put zero

#### My query

```
select ?item (SUM(?finalWeight) as ?summedFinalWeight) {
 ?item :hasContext ?context .
  optional 
  {
    ?context :doNotRecommend true .
    bind( 0 as ?cutWeight) 
  }
  optional
  {
    ?context :weight ?weight .
  } 
  bind ( if(bound(?cutWeight), ?cutWeight , if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.1) ) as ?finalWeight )
}
group by ?item
```

#### The result

[image]

look at the value for `:item`, it is `0.2` (i know the reason, it is because of 0.2 plus zero (and this zero is because the doNotRecommend is there) but i dont' know the solution, what I want is to have zero in the case of `:item`

(hint, i know that i can always run another query in an upper level of this query and solve it or i can solve it using filter not exist but i am looking to solve it in the same query, because what i should u is a minimal data, while in my ontology, getting that weight and these objects is a very long query

#### Update 1

This is my real query, the first part (before the union) checks if the users confirms to a context, the second part (after the union) checks if the user don't conform to a context **and here i want to check if that context has a doNotRecommendOrNot** . Please be sure that **it is imporisslbe that two parts validate together**

```
SELECT  ?item (SUM(?finalWeightFinal) AS ?userContextWeight)
WHERE
  { VALUES ?user { bo:ania }
    ?item  rdf:type  rs:RecommendableClass
    OPTIONAL
      {   { FILTER EXISTS { ?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass }
            ?item     rdf:type           rs:RecommendableClass .
            ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                      rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                      rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass
            FILTER EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }
            OPTIONAL
              { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched  ?weight }
            BIND(if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.2) AS ?finalWeight)
          }
        UNION
          { ?item     rdf:type           rs:RecommendableClass .
            ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                      rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                      rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass
            FILTER EXISTS { ?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass }
            FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }
            OPTIONAL
                #Here is the skip
              { ?userContext  rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch  true
                BIND(0 AS ?skip)
              }
            OPTIONAL
              { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch  ?weight }
            BIND(if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.1) AS ?finalWeight)
          }
      }
    BIND(if(bound(?finalWeight), ?finalWeight, 1) AS ?finalWeightFinal)
  }
GROUP BY ?item
```

#### Update 2

After the appreciate answer of @Joshua Taylor, I tried to applied his approach in the real case, but this time with adding `filter !bound(?skip)`

Here is the query

```
SELECT  ?item ?itemClass ?userContext ?skip ?finalWeight 
WHERE
  { #{ 
    in this block i just select the items that i want to calculate the user context to.
    } #
    OPTIONAL
      { FILTER EXISTS { ?item  rdf:type  ?itemClass }
        ?userContext  rdf:type       rs:UserContext ;
                  rs:appliedOnItems  ?itemClass ;
                  rs:appliedOnUsers  ?userClass
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched  ?weightMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch  ?weightNotMatched }
        OPTIONAL
          { ?userContext  rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch  true
            BIND(1 AS ?skip)
          }
        BIND(if(EXISTS { ?user  rdf:type  ?userClass }, coalesce(?weightMatched, "default User Matched"), coalesce(?weightNotMatched, "default User not matched")) AS ?weight)
      }
    BIND(if(bound(?weight), ?weight, "no user context found for this item") AS ?finalWeight)
    FILTER ( ! bound(?skip) )
  }
```

It works with the data that I have but I just have a test data right now so i want to ask you if it is correct

#### update 3

my query generates these fields:

`item skip ...`

and the filter removes the rows that does have a binding for skip, but let's say that an item has two rows, like this:

`item skip`

`A   1`

`A`

`A`

so in my case i will just remove the first row, i need to know if i can remove the all rows for that item please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this;  here's one that gets each item's sum weight, and then checks whether the item has a do not recommend flag, and if it does, uses 0 as the total weight:

```sql
select ?item (if(bound(?skip), 0.0, ?sumWeight_) as ?sumWeight) {
  { select ?item (sum(?weight) as ?sumWeight_) where {
      ?item :hasContext/:weight ?weight .
    }
    group by ?item
  }
  bind(exists { ?item :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true } as ?skip)
}
```

```
----------------------------
| item         | sumWeight |
============================
| :item        | 0.0       |
| :anotherItem | 0.0       |
----------------------------
```

Conceptually, this query checks once for each item whether any of its contexts mark it as non-recommendable.  I think that's relatively efficient.

### On **bind(exists { … } as ?skip)**

Note that combination of **bind** and **exists**.  You already know how **bind** works, as you've used it plenty of times. **bind(expr as ?variable)** evaluates the expression **expr** and assigns it to the variable **?variable**.  You'd probably used **exists** and (**not exists**) in **filter** expressions before.  **exists { … }** is true if the pattern inside the braces matches in the graph, and false otherwise. **not exists { … }** is similar, but reversed.  The pattern

```
?item :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true
```

is just shorthand, using a property path, for the pattern:

```
?item :hasContext ?something .
?something :doNotrecommend true .
```

In this case, if that pattern exists, then we want to skip the item's sum weight and use zero instead.

### Alternative

If you're willing to compute the sum for all the items, and then exclude those that have at least non-recommendable context, you can do that, too.  The trick is just to figure out how to count the number of skips:

```
select ?item (sum(?weight_) as ?weight){
  ?item :hasContext ?context .
  ?context :weight ?weight_ .
  bind(exists { ?context :doNotRecommend true } as ?skip)
}
group by ?item
having (sum(if(?skip,1,0)) = 0)
```

### Considerations

You mentioned that

> i know that i can always run another query in an upper level of this
>   query and solve it or i can solve it using filter not exist but i am
>   looking to solve it in the same query, because what i should u is a
>   minimal data, while in my ontology, getting that weight and these
>   objects is a very long query

The solution above computes the sum weights first, and then decides which to use and which to discard.  That means that there's some unnecessary computation.  Your solution does something similar:  it computes weights for contexts that don't have the :doNotRecommend property, even if some other context for the same item has a doNotRecommend property.  If you really want to avoid the unnecessary computation, then you should figure out which items are recommendable first, and then compute scores for those, and figure out which items are not recommendable, and just return zero for those.

It's easy to get a list of which items are which:  something like

```
select distinct ?item ?skip {
  ?item :hasContext ?anything .
  bind(exists{ :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true} as ?skip)
}
```

will do it just fine.  However, since you'd want to do different things with the skippable and the non-skippable values, and that would probably take the form of a union of the two alternatives, and then you have the problem that you'd have to repeat the same subquery in each one. (Or use **exists** in one and **not exists** in the other, which is essentially repeating the same query.)  It would get ugly pretty quickly.  It might look something like this:

```sql
select ?item ?weight {
  {
     #-- get non recommendable items and
     #-- set their weights to 0.0.
     select distinct ?item (0.0 as ?weight) {
       ?item :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true      #-- (*)
     }
  }
  union
  {
     #-- get recommendable items and
     #-- their aggregate weights
     select ?item (sum(?weight_) as ?weight) {
       #-- find the recommendable items
       { select distinct ?item {
           ?item :hasContext ?x .
           filter not exists { ?item :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true }   #-- (*)
         }
       }
       #-- and get their context's weights.
       ?item :hasContext/:weight ?weight_
     }
     group by ?item
  }
}
```

```
-------------------------
| item         | weight |
=========================
| :item        | 0.0    |
| :anotherItem | 0.9    |
-------------------------
```

The problem, in my opinion, is that the lines marked with **(*)** are really doing the same thing.  The other computation doesn't happen multiple times, which is good, but we're still checking twice for each item whether it's recommendable or not.

Comment: thank you for answering, please what does `bind(exists { ?item :hasContext/:doNotRecommend true } as ?skip)` mean?

Comment: @AniaDavid I updated the answer with some more explanation

Comment: maybe i get it, you are trying to say, check if that item has a context and that context has a true for recommended, right?

Comment: Oh i didn't see you update, sorry, that is a good solution but actually, in my real data, there is no direct predicate between the item and the context, there is a very big query to check whether there is acontext or not and whether there is a value for the users that achieving the context and default valeus, (so many) as you may know

Comment: can I show you my real query? (36 lines long) not so long

Comment: @AniaDavid Sure;  add it to the end of the question, but dont remove the any of the existing stuff from the question.  The existing question is a pretty good minimal example.

Comment: *The existing question is a pretty good minimal example* Yes I did it B-), I'm proud of me

Comment: Okay thank you, i've updated the question, and added a comment where the situation that doNotRecommend is applied

Comment: *and that would probably take the form of a union of the two alternatives, and then you have the problem that you'd have to repeat the same subquery in each one. (Or use exists in one and not exists in the other, which is essentially repeating the same query.)* you predicated my query before I even showed you, that's epic.

Comment: @AniaDavid It would be nice if SPARQL supported a notion of "temporary graph" like some SQL engines support temporary tables.  It'd be great if we could `select ?item ?recommendable into <#temp> { ... }` in one part so that later we could `{ select ... from <#temp> { ... }} union { select ... from <#temp> { ... }}`, or something like that.

Comment: I am trying to add the skip to my query, as in the update 1 i made, but no success yet, imagine a case where there are 4 userContext, and the user confirms to two of them with weights (0.1 and 0.4), and doesn't confirm to the other two with weights (0.3 and 0.4) but one of these context has the doNotRecommend, i am still getting not zero. could you check please ? and I am still trying as well

Comment: sorry for late, I am trying your approach on my querying using `coalesce` and `bind exist`

Comment: please could you check my update please? i tried to apply your way and your previus answer on another question to minimuse the query and remove the items that dont' have doNotRecommend but I used the filter on the upper side of the query with a subquery that takes the items that I want to calculate the user context to. could you have a look please ?

Comment: I made a third update to show your the negative way of my way, please could you help ?

Comment: @AniaDavid In your last update, you're filtering on each context based on whether or not it's non-recommendable, but you really want to filter *items* based on whether they have an context that is non-recommendable.  It's really just coincidence that the criteria for exclusion is in a similar place to the weights that you want to sum up.  The exclusion needs to happen per-item, not per-context.

Comment: the `doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch` is applied actually to the context (in the real data) not to the item,

Comment: what could be a solution, in my opinion, is if we can do the aggregation on the items, and remove the items that has at least one binding for skip.

Comment: **" the doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch is applied actually to the context (in the real data) not to the item"** Yes, I know where the triple is, but when you're it's the *item* that you want to exclude, not the individual context.  The exclusion is for the item, and you exclude an item when `{ ?item :hasContext ?context . ?context :doNotRecommend true }` matches.  That is how you know when to exclude the *item*.

Comment: Okay I got you, i tried to change the filter to : `FILTER not exists {  ?item a ?itemClass . ?userContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass  . ?userContext rs:doNotRecommendInCaseNotMatch true }` but the items that have two context and one of them doesn't have doNotRecomed keeps appearing, is there a mistake in my filter please?

Comment: @AniaDavid See the updated "Alternative" section.  It does what you mentioned in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621269/sparql-check-for-existing-of-a-property-and-give-zero-to-the-answer/36622501?noredirect=1#comment60850409_36622501).

Comment: hello, i will check after 3 hours, i am sorry i have to go

Comment: i really appreciate all the efforts

Comment: hello, applying your new `alternative` section, i get empty results,

Comment: it is working as a charm, thank you very very much, and so sorry for late, appreciate the amazing efforts, i wish i could help someday

Comment: hello, hope you're very well, i've found a new bug in fuseki, this is the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690863/datetime-comparing-with-now-function-is-not-working-on-sparql could you help please? i sent them to this mail thing, no one replies,